# string copied to character array

Tags: c++, string

I'm using C++14 and as per my understanding std::string in C++11 and above are terminated by null character. 
I'm unable to understand why the below code does not work.

```
string a="your";
char b[5];
for(int i=0; a[i]! ='\0';i++) 
b[i] =a[i] ;
cout<<b;
```

Output is:
"yourul"(followed by 2 random characters)

Comment: *"as per my understanding std::string in C++11 and above are terminated by null character"* That's where you are wrong. `a[i]` for `i > 4` invokes UB.

Comment: @BaummitAugen - Then [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) should be amended.

Comment: @BaummitAugen But shouldn't `a[4]` be `'\0'`?  That's my reading of the description here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/

Comment: @BaummitAugen is wrong. a[a.size()] == '\0' is guaranteed by the specification.

Comment: Ah true, had remembered that wrong. Actual problem would be that `b` is not \0 terminated.

Comment: The problem is that you are not copying the null character, not that the null character is not there.

Comment: Thanks @Szabolcs. It works after I copy the null character as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you don't copy the terminator to the destination array. Instead you end the loop when you encounter it (without copying it).

Without knowing the use-case or the need for the array (there seldom is any), don't use manual copying like that. If, for whatever reason you can't use e.g. `a.c_str()` or `a.data()` or even `&a[0]`, then use [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy) instead:

```
strncpy(b, a.c_str(), sizeof b - 1);  // -1 to leave space for the terminator
b[sizeof b - 1] = '\0';  // And make sure string is terminated
```

---

Do note that the guarantee of an existing terminator in the `std::string` object depends on the C++ standard used. Before C++11 there were no guarantees that the terminator existed in the string. In practice it still did (for simplicity's sake) but there were no guarantees by the specification.

Comment: Can you use sizeof operator without parens?! :o this looks nasty! :)

Comment: @W.F. Parenthesis are needed for *type-names*, not for general expressions.

Comment: Didn't know that... Thanks!

Comment: b=a. c_str() ; is giving me incompatible types in assignment of 'const char*'  to 'char [5]'

Comment: @VishalSharma You can't assign to an array, only *copy* to it.

Comment: @VishalSharma And I mean that instead of using the (temporary?) array `b`, use one of the access-functions directly when you think the array is needed.

Comment: Understood.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

So `std::string` does have the backwards compatibility guaranteed that the sequences returned by `c_str()` and `data()` are 0-terminated, and that `s[s.size()]` gives you a NUL. (Note that writing over any of these terminators is undefined behavior.)

However, your code has a different bug: the loop terminates the moment it encounters the NUL, and does not copy it over to `b`. So the last element of `b` has unspecified content, and reading it is undefined behavior.

Don't write the copy loop yourself. Use `strlen` or one of its variants. Or better yet, if at all possible, don't use writeable C-style strings at all.